# Register access in ATMEGA32 & Debugging of Serial Communication Atmel Studio

Tags: embedded, atmel, atmega

I am working upon ATMEGA32 and programming it with the help of Atmel Studio 6.0.............

In ATMEGA32, there are 32 general purpose registers starting from R00 to R31........but how can i use those registers directly in c language in Atmel Studio 6.0.......

R00 = x; instruction does not work...................so i am forced to use integer variables, but i want to use inbuilt registers so i can easily debug it how can i do it??????

My 2nd question is i am using USB to serial asynchronous communication, so while debugging i want that some value should be passes virtually via serial communication so that i can check my code...................how can i do that in Atmel Studio 6.0??????

Comment: If you want to deal with registers, you write assembly code.

Comment: But i have written my code in c and i have to use for and if elseif statements, so c is easy.........can i write assembly language in c program???

Comment: Yes, you can.  It's called "inline assembly".  But you have to be careful in understanding assumptions your C compiler has made about which registers it controls for compiling the C code.

Comment: [This link](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_reg_usage) might be helpful...

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? If your problem is "how can I easily debug my code on ATMEGA32", please rephrase your question. Interfering with the registers is not a good idea.

Comment: I have 2 problems and both of them i have included in the above que......My 1st problem is how can i access general purpose registers of ATMEGA32 in my c code.............My 2nd problem is since i have used serial communication if i want to check it in my AtmelStudio 6.0 how can i debug my code related to serial communication since i cnt give serial inputs and outputs on my tool

Comment: @TJD : Can u please give me the syntax or example of the use of assembly language in a c program........

Comment: @KaranShah, in your C code, you add statements like this: `asm("movw    r24, r28");`